# sql management studio diagram does not open

Tags: sql, management-studio-express

Hi I want to open the diagram I created in sql, but when I click to open it, sql management studio closes without any error.

Comment: What kind of diagram you are talking about? Please be more specific.

Comment: have you checked the Windows error logs